# What media type are SVGs treated as in assets?

Tags: assets

When SVGs are uploaded to assets what media type does CraftCMS associate them with? Image, Document, HTML or XML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Image. Use the [`kind`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.assets#kind) parameter to filter them out.